# EPF Importer error in mariadb 10.2 - encoding?

Tags: python, mysql, database, mariadb

I am using EPFImporter tool by Apple to import their feed data to database.
on one server i have
*mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.24-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1* and this works fine without errors.

But on another where:
*mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.11-MariaDB, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using readline 5.1* things got tricky.
Apple EPF data are in UTF8 my databases both are in UTF8 but on 10.2 I cannot import records because of weird errors (screenshots attached).

All solution I found on Internet didn't worked and were always reffering to old MySQL.
[image]

[image]

So basically I'm stuck. Have no idea if this is MariaDB issue, database issue or python MySQLdb issue. In both cases I used the same 'video' datafile and on old server it works while on new it not. Both cases UTF8 encoding set, and same version of mysqldb module, and same version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

You need `utf8mb4` in MySQL -- both in table/column declarations and in the connection.

Your  needs a 4-byte UTF-8 code.  MySQL's `utf8` only handles 3 bytes; `utf8mb4` is needed for the rest of UTF-8.